# which is the best wood for a patio set?

Tags: woodworking

Hi it is the first time for me to woodwork.. I would like to know which is the best and resistant wood to built a [patio set](http://www.clasf.co.za/ninf/?category=home-and-garden&subcategory=furniture&subcategory2=&subcategory3=&province=&city=&priceini=&pricefin=&filter_search=wooden%20patio). I'd like two chairs, small table and umbrella.

Comment: Welcome to SE. As we're not a discussion forum, one specific question per post, please.

Comment: Redwood is the longest lasting of all the wood I have used for decking and tables but it is expensive. Cedar would be the next best but if not sealed well the splinters can be a real pain in ,,, where ever they get you.

Comment: If this is your first time making furniture then I would recommend cheap, easy to work, pine because it takes some practice to flush out ideas. Furniture building may require some new tools as well. Besides being somewhat mold resistant, redwood is also commonly used because it is soft (making it more comfortable).

Answer (score 2):

Redwood, cedar, and teak are probably the most common rot-resistant species used for outdoor furniture. The first two are a pleasure to work with, but they're very soft. That means that they can be damaged more easily. Teak tends to be less common and/or more expensive.

Pine (or spruce or fir) is inexpensive and can actually last quite some time if properly sealed and not left in consistently damp environments.